# React - useParams() won't fail null / undefined check

Tags: reactjs

I have two routes, `/Profile` which shows the user their own profile.
(it doesnt need to request this because their profile is already stored in state)

Then the second `/Profile/....` which shows the user other profiles.
(it does need to request this because the state does not store all other users)

To have this functionality I have tried inputting this undefined / null check but it doesn't fail when the params are empty:

```
  const getRequest = async () => {
    const user_response = null;
    console.log("param",params)
    console.log("param id",params.id)

    if (params !== null || params !== undefined) {
      console.log("params true")

      if (params.id !== null || params.id !== undefined) {
        console.log("id true")
      }
      else{
        console.log("false")
      }
    }
    else{
       console.log("false")
    }
```

The following is the console outputs when no params are passed:

```
> param {}
> param id undefined
> params true
> id true
```

The following is the console outputs when params are passed:

```
> param {id: '321'}
> param id 321
> params true
> id true
```

How can I make it work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user ID can't be falsy (e.g. `0` is not a valid user ID, or `''` isn't), then just

```
const userId = params?.id || null;
```

without any other fuss – `userId` it'll be either the ID if it's truthy, or `null`.

Answer (score 1):

the empty object still return true, so if you want to check the object is empty or not you must do something like this:

```
const obj = {};
const isEmpty = Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
```

then you can check the param object with this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you're not passing any params, "params" is default an empty object which is bypassing your if statementes ( because it is actually different than null and undefined)
You need a more clear condition; can use lodash library which has a method _.isEmpty() to check for empty objects or as other have stated use the Object.Keys length

Comment: While I do appreciate your explanation, I think a library for this functionality is a little overkill.